# How to handle password related tasks in FireFox WebExtensions?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

There have been many really great extensions for FireFox which has been nullified by the WebExtensions change, like "*Master Password Timeout*", "*Password Maker*", or "*Unhide Passwords*".

I am not an ext developer but some of these are really almost one-liners (like *Master PW Timeout*), so I thought it'd be trivial to port ot over. However I wasn't able to find any info about the required API calls, methods, or really anything related to anything passwordy.

Is it possible to convert these somehow that they actually **work under latest FireFox** (like nightly and future releases)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Firefox developers are not quite clear about what they want; some insists to drop the internal password support altogether and use external wallet providers, others are pretty busy creating the API required for modern secure data storage.

The API is not there yet, but you can follow its progress in various Bugzilla tickets:

- [Master password API for WebExtensions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1359182)
- [Land logins API](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1324919)
- [Security review of logins API](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1357856)
- [Implement login storage API](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1344788)

I should update this answer as things progress.